# Why am I not getting a return from my button - Message Box Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, tkinter, messagebox

For my game, I need to ask the user to choose a difficulty to start the game but I'm having difficulty to get When the code below is run instead of getting the right return from my button, the button disappears and I get a return of *None*. This is my code:

```
def start_game():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.attributes("-topmost", True)
    root.withdraw()
    answer = messagebox.askyesno("Welcome to Snake!", "Would you like to play?")
    if answer == True:
        root.deiconify()
        mainLabel = tk.Label(root, text='Choose a dificulty: ')

        def easy_difficulty():
            print('easy')
            return 1
        def medium_difficulty():
            print('medium')
            return 5
        def hard_difficulty():
            print('hard')
            return 10

        easy_ask = tk.Button(root, text='Easy', command=easy_difficulty())
        medium_ask = tk.Button(root, text='Medium', command=medium_difficulty())
        hard_ask = tk.Button(root, text='Hard', command=hard_difficulty())

        mainLabel.pack()
        easy_ask.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        medium_ask.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        hard_ask.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    root.destroy()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. I'm not sure if it's the only issue, but you likely don't want the parentheses in `command=easy_difficulty()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not destroy your root element right away. An if statement is not a loop. Your code continues to run after, and your root element gets destroyed.

Delete `root.destroy()`.

Also, when you specify a command in a tk button, you dont need the opening and closing brackets. you just do

```
easy_ask = tk.Button(root, text='Easy', command=easy_difficulty)
```

If you are wondering why, command parameter stores the memory address of the function, and runs it on click. If you put the brackets there, you have already ran the function, which returns `None` in this case. When you click on the button, tk attempts to run `None`.

Comment: I tried what you said and it worked but I still get no answer but i still don't get a return value when a button is pressed.

Comment: @Vicdenz You can't get the return value from a callback triggered by clicking a button.  Try assigning the required value to a global variable.

Comment: @acw1668 is right, I forgot to mention. I suggest not using global variables, but running the necessary code inside the function that is triggered by the button. Plan your code well.